# Db2 relocate from v10 to v11 on LUW with upgrade

Tags: database, db2, upgrade, relocation

here is my problem:

I have a server with DB2 v10.5.9 and v11.1.4.4 installed. I updated the server, instances and dbs that were there at the time and it all wirks great. Now I have added a new volume to the system that contains a DB in version 10.5.9 and I need to relocate it and upgrade it to v11.1.4.4. The relocate within v10 is not a problem but I can't do the relocate in the v11 with that DB. A command "db2 catalog db on /system/metalog/" doesn't work either.

I have the relocate.cfg file that should work, but all my commands go against the v11 of course since that is the default db now.

My idea was:

```
db2 catalog db testdb on /system/testdb/metalog/
db2 upgrade db testdb
```

What must I do to do the relocate and then the upgrade so I can use that DB in v11.

This is what I did to get the correct folder structur:

```
mkdir -p data/testdb/NODE0000
mkdir -p metalog/testdb
mkdir -p /db2/backup/testdb/testdb1/archivlogfiles/
mv metalog/olddb/NODE0000/ metalog/testdb/
mkdir data/testdb/NODE0000/TESTDB1
mv data/testdb/NODE0000/OLDDB1/ data/testdb/NODE0000/TESTDB1/
```

Here is the relocate.cfg

```
DB_NAME=OLDDB1,TESTDB1
DB_PATH=/db2/olddb/data/olddb1/metalog/,/db2/testdb/data/testdb/testdb1/metalog
INSTANCE=olddb,testdb
STORAGE_PATH=/db2/olddb/data/olddb1/data/,/db2/testdb/data/testdb/testdb1/data/
LOG_DIR=/db2/olddb/data/olddb1/metalog/olddb/NODE0000/SQL00001/LOGSTREAM0000/,/db2/testdb/data/testdb/testdb1/metalog/testdb/NODE0000/SQL00001/
LOGARCHMETH1=DISK:/db2/backup/testdb/testdb1/archivlogfiles/
CONT_PATH=/db2/olddb/data/olddb1/data/olddb1_TS_32PART.dbf,/db2/testdb/data/testdb/testdb1/data/olddb1_TS_32PART.dbf
```

This is the relocate log:

```
Logging started at Mon May  4 11:29:10 2020
   Input file: /db2/testdb/scripts/relocate_olddb1.cfg

Opening configuration file.
  -> File: "/db2/testdb/scripts/relocate_olddb1.cfg"

Changes requested:

  -> Database name:

      Old: "olddb1"
      New: "testdb1"

  -> Database path:

      Old: "/db2/olddb/data/olddb1/metalog/"
      New: "/db2/testdb/data/testdb/testdb1/metalog/"

  -> Instance name:

      Old: "olddb"
      New: "testdb"

  -> Node number: 0

  -> Log directory:

      Old: "/db2/testdb/data/testdb/testdb1/metalog/testdb/NODE0000/SQL00001/"
      New: "/db2/testdb/data/testdb/testdb1/metalog/testdb/NODE0000/SQL00001/"

  -> Container paths:

      Old: "/db2/olddb/data/olddb1/data/olddb1_TS_32PART.dbf"
      New: "/db2/testdb/data/testdb/testdb1/data/olddb1_TS_32PART.dbf"

  -> Storage paths:

      Old: "/db2/olddb/data/olddb1/data"
      New: "/db2/testdb/data/testdb/testdb1/data"

SD mode: no

** PASS #1: Verifying Files and Structures **
Opening the local directory file.
  -> File: "/db2/testdb/data/testdb/testdb1/metalog/testdb/NODE0000/sqldbdir/sqldbdir"

Reading directory header.
Reading hash offset table.
Reading 1 entries into memory.
Opening the global log control file

ERROR: Unable to open global log control file.
       Path = "/db2/testdb/data/testdb/testdb1/metalog/testdb/NODE0000/SQL00001/"
       DB2 RC = 0x801008dc


ERROR: Failed to initialize member configuration information.
       DB2 RC = 0x801008dc


Exiting with RC = 1.


Logging stopped at Mon May  4 11:29:10 2020
```

My db2level is set to db2 v11.1.4.4.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Enable the `db2relocatedb` utility tracing with `export DB2RELOCATEDB_LOGFILE=/tmp/relocate.log` in your session and repeat the `db2relocatedb` call on v11.1. Edit your question with exact contents of your relocate.cfg file, cp / mv commands on db2 files / directories you did before running this command, and exact error message you get instead of your current "doesn't work" statement + `/tmp/relocate.log` file contents.

Comment: `db2diag -rc 0x801008dc`: `GLFH/LFH/MFH format version is not equal to the DB's format version`. What's the db2 code level of these instances: `olddb` and `testdb`? Are they both at 11.1? Have you upgraded `OLDDB1` to 11.1, if `olddb` is at 11.1?

Comment: `Log directory` in the `log` file doesn't correspond to your `cfg` file. Have you really provided the correct `relocate.cfg` file? And I don't see the corresponding `chown` commands. Have you run them appropriately?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein the olddb is v10.5.9 and the testdb shouldbe v11.1.4.4 that is my problem I want to relocate a v10 DB to a v11 enviroment. I have v10 and v11 server installed but I can't get into the v10 enviroment to do the relocate to then switch and to the update db.

Comment: chown is correct since it is the same user. The LOG dir works, since if I do the relocate under v10 to v10 it works.

Comment: @Viking  For db2relocatedb, IBM documents `The new instance must be at the same release level as the instance where the database currently resides.`. Investigate creating a fresh V10.5.0.9 Db2-instance into which to copy the database files from the new volume, and then upgrade that fresh V10.5.0.9 instance+database before running the v11.1 db2relocatedb. See the Usage Notes for db2relocatedb in the Db2 Knowledge Centre. Rehearse first on a non-production environment. Other approaches  include restoring a  V10.5.0.9 Db2-backup into a Db2 v11.1 Db2-instance (restore does db upgrade).

Comment: @Viking The same user is an owner of 2 different db2 instances? It's not possible. Very strange `LOG_DIR` setting in your cfg file. What's the output of `db2 get db cfg for olddb1 | grep "Path to log"`?